# How do I find the domain of this function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I would like to know which operations i have to do to get the domain of this function: 
$$y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}$$

I have researched and the solution of the inequality $\frac{1}{x}-1 \geq 0$  is

$$0<x \leq 1$$

Which are the steps to get this result?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about what numbers you're allowed to take square roots of?

Comment: @Semiclassical, What I have done is $(1/x)-1>=0$, after that $1/x>=1$ and finally the result that I got was $x>=1$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\dfrac{1}{x} - 1 \geq 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \dfrac{1 - x}{x} \geq 0 
$$
Below we elaborate diagram of signals for the functions $f(x) = 1 - x$ and $g(x) = x$. 
[image]

The signs of the third row were obtained by dividing the signal by the first signal from the second row in each sector. Thus, 
$$
S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 < x \leq 1\}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We need to consider positive values for $x$ because $x<0\implies1/x-1<0$ and $x=0$ means that $1/x-1$ is undefined.

So
$$1/x-1\ge0$$
$$1/x\ge1$$
$$x\cdot1/x\ge x\cdot1$$
$$1\ge x$$
$$x\le1$$
thus (because $x\gt0$)
$$0\lt x\le 1$$

Answer (score 1):

We need $1/x-1\ge 0$ to be able to take the square root. If $x$ is positive i.e. $x>0$, this is equivalent to
$$1-x\ge0$$
$$x\le 1$$
So $x$ must satisfy $0< x\le1$.